# How Can I Whitelist an Firebase App?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, whitelist

We are trying to whitelist an iOS/Android app that is built with Firebase. The goal is to identify the data that these apps use so that it will not count towards users' data usage.

In the simple scenario, just whitelisting the IP address of the Firebase database would be enough. However, I have spoken with Firebase support and they can't provide static IP addresses as they change often. The other option would be the domain name but that also can't work since the Firebase connection is established over HTTPS.

One last option is using the [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), however Firebase responded indicating that it wouldn't be an option.

That leaves me no options so I wanted to turn to the Stackoverflow community to see if anyone was able to whitelist an Firebase app.

Thanks,
Guven.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to whitelist your app? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I wasn't able to. It still bothers me!

Comment: were you able to do it?

Comment: Nope, there was no option to whitelist.

Comment: Did you find a solution 2020?

Comment: @MerhawiFissehaye nope: (

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm facing the same issue, there's no IP given by firebase function that I could whitelist. I thought I could use VPC but no support for that either, github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/552

Comment: nope @vignz.pie, nothing yet. Maybe you could also upvote the question so that it gets some visibility?

Comment: No progress on this, end of 2021 :)